# Storm Error: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read

Tags: r, apache-storm

I am running a storm topology on a local cluster and it works fine for about an hour and then it stops after throwing this error.

```
backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
```

The entire error trace is:

```
ERROR b.s.t.ShellBolt - Halting process: ShellBolt died. Command: [Rscript, stormtest_with_OR1.R], ProcessInfo pid:32381, name:RBolt exitCode:-1, errorString:
java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:
    at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:101) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:321) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_67]
2016-04-05 11:07:04,665 FATAL Unable to register shutdown hook because JVM is shutting down.
51144 [Thread-14-RBolt] ERROR b.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:336) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__7184$fn__7185.invoke(worker.clj:532) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__5523$fn__5524.invoke(executor.clj:261) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:489) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_67]
```

The Bolt is written in R. In my topology code the cluster.shutdown() is commented which has been cited as the reason for this error in many [threads](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-531) related to this error.

Comment: Does the R part run off the cluster?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Sorry, I did not get what you mean?? R 3.2 is installed on that machine.

Comment: If you run the R script alone, does it finish?

Comment: Yeah, the R code works fine. It is generating output for quite a long time. Don't know why it stops after some time?

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Somehow hacked it...It's been long...as much as I remember there was an issue with the ack function of the package. Commented the ack() and it worked without throwing this error. Don't think it's the correct way to go.